# Compare two integer sequences at compile-time?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates

Let's say I have a `constexpr std::integer_sequence<...>` object. At compile-time, I perform some operations on it, and then I want to `static_assert` that it is `==` some other `std::integer_sequence<...>`. Given that the `integer_sequence` is a type, how would I provide an overloaded  `constexpr bool operator==` that would appropriately compare them?

A more concrete example: converting `int` to `std::integer_sequence<char>`. That is, conversion of integer to a character sequence ([inspired by Peter Sommerlad's talk at CPPCon '15](https://github.com/PeterSommerlad/Publications/blob/master/CPPCon/variable_templates/multiplication_table/src/multiplication_table.cpp))

I have some function that I'm pretty confident will appropriately convert a decimal integer value less than 1000 to a 4 element character sequence:

```
#include <utility> // integer_sequence

template<char... t>
using char_sequence = std::integer_sequence<char, t...>;
constexpr char make_digit_char(const size_t digit, const size_t power_of_ten=1, const char zero_replacement = ' ')
{
    return char(digit>=power_of_ten?digit/power_of_ten+'0':zero_replacement);
}

template<int num>
constexpr auto int_to_char_sequence()
{
    static_assert(num < 1000, "Cannot handle integers larger than 1000!");
    //format for up to 1000
    return char_sequence<' ', 
                    make_digit_char(num,100), 
                    make_digit_char(num%100,10,num>=100?'0':' '),
                    '0' + num % 10>{};
}
```

However, I don't trust myself, so I want to write some tests:

```
static_assert(char_sequence<' ', ' ', ' ', '0'>{} == int_to_char_sequence<0>(), "failed to convert 0 to char sequence");
static_assert(char_sequence<' ', ' ', ' ', '1'>{} == int_to_char_sequence<1>(), "failed to convert 1 to char sequence");
// ...
static_assert(char_sequence<' ', '1', '1', '1'>{} == int_to_char_sequence<111>(), "failed to convert 111 to char sequence")
```

and also want to test `!=`:

```
// ...
static_assert(char_sequence<' ', '1', '1', '1', '2'>{} != int_to_char_sequence<111>(), " 1 1 1 2 should not be equal to 111");
static_assert(int_to_char_sequence<111>() != char_sequence<' ', '1', '1', '1', '2'>{}, " 111 should not be equal to  1 1 1 2");
```

So I have a few requirements for my equivalence operators:

- The data in the sequence is stored in the type, so two character sequences are fundamentally different types
- What if one character sequence is longer than the other?
- The operators need to be `constexpr` so that `static_assert` will work

  - which means we can't do any sort of conversion to `std::array` and compare

#### How do I accomplish this?

---

Authors note:
I did not find another post on SO that could do compile-time equality for integer sequences, so I answered my own question below. This is my own work to accomplish that, and I in no way claim it to be the optimal method. If you have a better approach, please post it as another answer and I'll accept it instead!

Comment: Wouldn't [`std::is_same](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) suffice for this case?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Wow, I didn't even consider that. Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a shorter version:

```
template <char... A, char... B>
constexpr bool operator==(char_sequence<A...>, char_sequence<B...>)
{
    return std::is_same<char_sequence<A...>, char_sequence<B...>>::value;
}
```

The sequences are the same if and only if the types composed of those sequences are the same.

---

Though typically, you'd just test this directly:

```
template <int num>
using int_to_char_sequence_t = decltype(int_to_char_sequence<num>());

static_assert(std::is_same<
    int_to_char_sequence_t<0>,
    char_sequence<' ', ' ', ' ', '0'>
    >::value, "!");
```

Comment: There is some forehead slapping happening on my end. I didn't even consider `is_same`. I suppose I didn't fully wrap my head around the concept that the sequences are types, not objects.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid degrading type information into `constexpr` data if you can.

Second, overloading `==` on types dependent only on templates and types in `std` or built-in makes your program ill-formed, no diagnostic required, in the latest draft standard.

```
template<class T, T...ts>
struct sequence: std::integral_sequence<T,ts...> {
  constexpr sequence(){};
};
template<char...cs>
using chars = sequence<char, cs...>;

template<bool b>
using bool_t = std::integral_constant<bool, b>;

template<class T, T...as, T...bs>
bool_t<
  std::is_same< sequence<T, as...>, sequence<T,bs...>{}
> operator==( sequence<T, as...>, sequence<T, bs...> ) {
  return {};
}
```

this returns a `std::true_type` if the operation is equivalent, and `std::false_type` otherwise.

If used in a `bool` context, they have `constexpr operator bool()const` that does the right thing.  If used in other contexts, the information is kept as a type, not degraded to a mere compile-time value.

Comment: Why not just `std::is_same<X, Y>::type` as the return type instead of wrapping in `bool_t`?

Comment: @barry is same inherits from true false, it is not actually it.  Dunno if forcing actual true type is a good idea or not, but I like it.;

Comment: `::type` actually is `true_type` or `false_type`, no?

Comment: @barry gosh, it is!  Did not know that

Answer (score 1):

To handle the case of compile-time comparison, we will use a variadic function that allows us to pull off `chars` from the sequences, compare them, and then recurse on the rest of the sequences.

- Base case: Empty sequences (return true)
- Base case: One sequence is longer than the other (return false)
- Recursive case: non-empty sequences: compare heads of sequences, and then recurse
- Implement `!=` operator in terms of `==` operator

Code:

```
// empty character sequences
constexpr bool operator == (char_sequence<>, char_sequence<>)
{
    return true;
}

// character sequences with one element
template<char T, char... t>
constexpr bool operator == (char_sequence<T, t...>, char_sequence<>)
{
    return false;
}

template<char T, char... t>
constexpr bool operator == (char_sequence<>, char_sequence<T, t...>)
{
    return false;
}

// Recursive case
template<char S, char... s, char T, char... t>
constexpr bool operator == (char_sequence<S, s...>, char_sequence<T, t...>)
{
    return S == T && char_sequence<s...>{} == char_sequence<t...>{};
}

// operator != in terms of operator==
template<char... s, char... t>
constexpr bool operator != (char_sequence<s...>, char_sequence<t...>)
{
    return !(char_sequence<s...>{} == char_sequence<t...>{});
}
```

Code is shortened for readability; you should always declare your template methods before you define them.

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d6d30885ccaf7f8)